# Raspberry Pi3 bluetooth scanning issues

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, bluez, hci

I have installed an Raspberry Pi3 to collect information from TI SensorTags via Bluetooth. I installed the newest bluez on it. I used the hcitool for a few days, but it stopped to work suddenly. The problem is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2AnM.jpg
"sudo hcitool lescan" cannot scan the bluetooth devices' MAC address, return with the following error: "Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error". I've tried to reset the tool, switch to "DOWN" and then "UP", soft and hard reset the Raspberry, reset the dbus, but it still doesnt work. After reinstall the bluez, the "lescan" works onece, than stop working. Any idea to correct this problem is good for me, pls help me. And sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: By the time you get the answer for this, why dont you try these tools as an alternate to scan your tags: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-the-generic-attribute-profile-gatt-in-bluetooth-low-energy . Regards aksonlyaks. Catch more bluetooth info on http://mre4less.com

Answer (score 0):

The reason why i didnt try other tools was simple, I wrote a Shell script(with the lescan command) before, and this works well. Anyway i have tried the scan-method from the article [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-the-generic-attribute-profile-gatt-in-bluetooth-low-energy-with-your-intel-edison) . 
Before i used this commands, the "sudo hcitool lescan" didnt work, return with the "Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error". 
The method works, but i dont know, how to automatize the scan, and write the scanned devices' address to a file.
After i used the method, the "sudo hcitool lescan" starts to work, but not properly. It can scan the devices, but sometimes cannot end the scan, or return with the MAC-addresses, with the usual error message. 
This is an interesting result, it seems i can continue the work, sadly dont know why. But this is enough, thanks @aksonlyaks .